# Ajax sorting through the whole array

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, api

Currently i have a project to create a webpage to show FIFA 2018 Matches and here's where I get the API: http://www.football-data.org/documentation

The connection code goes like this

```
   $.ajax({
      headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' },
      url: 'sample' ,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: filter code like ?timeFrame=n1 or ?matchday=1
      type: 'GET',
    }).done(function(response) {

    });
```

My problem now is I wanted to create an option so users could have the selection to sort the matches according to their match day or a time frame.

My code is basically like this, i changed a part of the ajax call to assign the value

```
url: $('#selectMatch').val() ,
```

The select code and function

```
<select  id="selectMatch">
        <option value="day1url">1 Day</option>
        <option value="day7url">7 Day</option>
        <option value="day10url">10 Day</option>
</select>

$(function(){

                $('#selectMatch').change(function(){
                  var matchURL= $(this).val();
                  return  matchURL;

            });
```

But when i click the option it will load the first choice not the other choices

Comment: Can you tell what exactly you want?

Comment: For a dropdown there is really only 1 choice, what do you mean it loads the first choice and not the others?